# IA en Javascript, el codigo esta bien pero no lo dibuja

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, inteligencia-artificial

El problema es el siguiente, estava mirando el video ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AKMSO2Gocs&ab_channel=RaduMariescu-Istodor") y en el minuto 11:30 comienza a hacer la parte donde se comete el error en el codigo. El tiene un repositorio en github he intentado copiar el codigo pero ni aun asi funciona.

repositorio ("https://github.com/gniziemazity/Self-driving-car/tree/main/3.%20Artificial%20sensors")

Solo voy a poner los codigos que se tocan en esta leccion del video ya que hay varios codigos

Comenzando por el primero: sensor.js

```
class Sensor{
    constructor(car){
        this.car=car;
        this.rayCount=5;
        this.rayLength=150;
        this.raySpread=Math.PI/2;

        this.rays=[];
        this.readings=[];
    }

    update(roadBorders){
        this.#castRays();
        this.readings=[];
        for(let i=0;i<this.rays.length;i++){
            this.readings.push(this.#getReading(this.rays[i],roadBorders));
        }
    }

    #getReading(ray,roadBorders){
        let touches=[];

        for(let i=0;i<roadBorders.length;i++){
            const touch=getIntersection(
                ray[0],
                ray[1],
                roadBorders[i][0],
                roadBorders[i][1]
            );
            if(touch){
                touches.push(touch);
            }
        }

        if(touches.length==0){
            return null;
        }else{
            const offsets=touches.map(e=>e.offset);
            const minOffset=Math.min(...offsets);
            return touches.find(e=>e.offset==minOffset);
        }
    }

    #castRays(){
        this.rays=[];
        for(let i=0;i<this.rayCount;i++){
            const rayAngle=lerp(
                this.raySpread/2,
                -this.raySpread/2,
                this.rayCount==1?0.5:i/(this.rayCount-1)
            )+this.car.angle;

            const start={x:this.car.x, y:this.car.y};
            const end={
                x:this.car.x-
                    Math.sin(rayAngle)*this.rayLength,
                y:this.car.y-
                    Math.cos(rayAngle)*this.rayLength
            };
            this.rays.push([start,end]);
        }
    }

    draw(ctx){
        for(let i=0;i<this.rayCount;i++){
            let end=this.rays[i][1];
            if(this.readings[i]){
                end=this.readings[i];
            }

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth=2;
            ctx.strokeStyle="yellow";
            ctx.moveTo(
                this.rays[i][0].x,
                this.rays[i][0].y
            );
            ctx.lineTo(
                end.x,
                end.y
            );
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth=2;
            ctx.strokeStyle="black";
            ctx.moveTo(
                this.rays[i][1].x,
                this.rays[i][1].y
            );
            ctx.lineTo(
                end.x,
                end.y
            );
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }        
}
```

En la linia de `this.readings.push(this.#getReading(this.rays[i],roadBorders));`
si yo quito `this.#getReading(this.rays[i],roadBorders` me va a funcionar pero si lo dejo puesto el canvas no me va a enseñar nada ni la carretera ni el coche.

Aqui esta el: car.js

```
class Car{
    constructor(x,y,width,height){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;

        this.speed=0;
        this.acceleration=0.2;
        this.maxSpeed=3;
        this.friction=0.05;
        this.angle=0;

        this.sensor=new Sensor(this);
        this.controls=new Controls();
    }

    update(roadBorders){
        this.#move();
        this.sensor.update(roadBorders);
    }

    #move(){
        if(this.controls.forward){
            this.speed+=this.acceleration;
        }
        if(this.controls.reverse){
            this.speed-=this.acceleration;
        }

        if(this.speed>this.maxSpeed){
            this.speed=this.maxSpeed;
        }
        if(this.speed<-this.maxSpeed/2){
            this.speed=-this.maxSpeed/2;
        }

        if(this.speed>0){
            this.speed-=this.friction;
        }
        if(this.speed<0){
            this.speed+=this.friction;
        }
        if(Math.abs(this.speed)<this.friction){
            this.speed=0;
        }

        if(this.speed!=0){
            const flip=this.speed>0?1:-1;
            if(this.controls.left){
                this.angle+=0.03*flip;
            }
            if(this.controls.right){
                this.angle-=0.03*flip;
            }
        }

        this.x-=Math.sin(this.angle)*this.speed;
        this.y-=Math.cos(this.angle)*this.speed;
    }

    draw(ctx){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.x,this.y);
        ctx.rotate(-this.angle);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(
            -this.width/2,
            -this.height/2,
            this.width,
            this.height
        );
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.restore();

        this.sensor.draw(ctx);
    }
}
```

Y por ultimo el: main.js

```
const canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.width=200;

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const road=new Road(canvas.width/2,canvas.width*0.9);
const car=new Car(road.getLaneCenter(1),100,30,50);

animate();

function animate(){
    car.update(road.borders);

    canvas.height=window.innerHeight;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(0,-car.y+canvas.height*0.7);

    road.draw(ctx);
    car.draw(ctx);

    ctx.restore();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Preguntarme cualquier cosa mas que necesiteis :)